# Migration of Cassandra DB cluster from AWS to Azure

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cassandra

We have one requirement to migrate Cassandra DB Cluster sitting over CentOS 6.5 from AWS to Azure. It is 4 node cluster with approx 3TB of data.

So how to meet this requirement?

We explored several methods mentioned below:

1. *Cassandra Replication*:  We created VPN tunnel b/w AWS and Azure and tried Cassandra Replication. // Failed.
2. *ASR*: We tried ASR for the migration, getting error :" *The data size for physical or virtual machine should be less than or equal to 1023 GB* ". ErrorID: 539.
3. *AMI to VHD conversion*: We are not able to find a way to convert AWS Linux AMI to Azure supported VHD.

No matter which method we choose, we are looking for a feasible solution for this.

Expect your reply.

Comment: Adding replicas/nodes in Azure and removing from AWS should work. Why did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

I would insure you are using the network topology replication strategy and the gossiping property file snitch, make sure you have SSL and the cluster secure and just create new nodes in Azure as their own DC then change the replication to include the new DC.

You can do this without a VPN assuming you have the cluster secured for doing this. Its what you use when you replicate between regions anyway in AWS.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for the answer, I did the same with premium storage VMs on Azure and worked perfectly.

Comment: Let me know if there is more detail you want before accepting the answer.